# SQL + goLang - running select statement with an IN condition - and passing it an array of ids?

Tags: mysql, sql, go

I want to perform the following logic -

```
SELECT some_column
FROM table_name
WHERE id IN (value1, value2, ...);
```

in my go code I have the following int array to represent my ids :

```
idsToGet := []int{1,2}
```

I fully understand that you might normally do a sprintf and pass in the one id you were looking for... BUT...

I feel like there is a sensible way to do this without iterating over the array, and doing this as a separate call for each ID... via sprintf - is there a way I can do this as just one call - and have my IN clause auto contain everything from my array?

Totally new to Go - been trying to solve this for an hour, I have it working for single id's - but not for multiples.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use `Sprintf` to put raw values into SQL, that's a bad habit. What you want to do is build a bit of SQL with the right number of placeholders and then let the library take care of replacing the placeholders with their value.

If you have two `int`s in your array then you want to build this:

```
SELECT some_column
FROM table_name
WHERE id IN (?, ?)
```

If you have four then you want to build:

```
SELECT some_column
FROM table_name
WHERE id IN (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

and so on. All you need is a simple function that can produce `n` placeholders; there are lots of ways to do this:

```
func placeholders(n int) string {
    ps := make([]string, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        ps[i] = "?"
    }
    return strings.Join(ps, ",")
}
```

or maybe:

```
func placeholders(n int) string {
    var b strings.Builder
    for i := 0; i < n - 1; i++ {
        b.WriteString("?,")
    }
    if n > 0 {
        b.WriteString("?")
    }
    return b.String()
}
```

or whatever is clearest to you, the implementation is unlikely to have any  measurable impact as long as it is correct.

Then you can say things like:

```
query := fmt.Sprintf("select some_column from table_name where id in (%s)", placeholders(len(idsToGet)))
rows, err := db.Query(query, idsToGet...)
```

and spin throw `rows` in the usual manner.